# Reference of scientific principle of multi verse in the Hindu mythology

Tags: universe

There have been references of many scientific and ultra modern discoveries in Hindu mythology like Time dilation in Mahabharata while Lord Krishna was giving the speech on Geeta .Also accurate measurement of speed of light etc. Is there any reference to the Multi verse  theory in the Indian scriptures.

Comment: Please Note that Scientific Speculations are off-topic on this site.